# How can I make a do while loop with an exception catch, continuous?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I try to catch the exception which finally works but now I need to figure out how to make it loop. ALso, how would I be able to get user input(int select) to the outside of the loop? I can try creating a new function, that might do the trick.

```
do {
    System.out.print("How many integers shall we compare? (Enter a positive integer): ");
    try {
        select = intFind.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        // Display the following text in the event of an invalid input
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
        intFind.nextLine();
    }
} while (select < 0);
```

Then

```
do
            {
                System.out.print("How many integers shall we compare? (Enter a positive integer): ");
                try {
                    b = Get();
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    // Display the following text in the event of an invalid input
                    System.out.println("Invalid input!");

                    intFind.nextLine();
                } copySel = b;  
            }while(select < 0);
```

and

```
static int Get()
    {
        Scanner intFind = new Scanner(System.in);
        int select;
        select = intFind.nextInt();
        return select;
    }
```

Comment: You want the user to enter a positive integer, but the condition in while clause checks for a number less than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it loop make sure that `select` is initialized to a value less than 0. But it would be better to have a condition `select < 2`, because it makes more sense to compare at least to values.

Create a method like

```
private int[] promptIntegers(int numberOfIntegers, Scanner sc) {
    int[] integers = new int[numberOfIntegers];
    //read ints
    //return the array
}
```

and call it like

```
select = intFind.nextInt();
int[] integers = promptIntegers(select, sc);
//do the comparison among the integers
```